# Returning to view as ToList() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code:

```
EmployeeEntities storeDB = new EmployeeEntities();
         public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var employee = storeDB.Employees.ToList() //ToList is not showing up!
                return View(employee);
            }
```

and my EmployeeEntities class looks like this:

```
 public class EmployeeEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Why I cannot see ToList() in my ActionResult Index() ???

Comment: I don't think you need to be showing all of that code for your problem. I suggest removing the View Page code. Although, you have got an answer which seems correct, you should avoid adding too much code bloat as it can deter some users from wanting to read the question and therefore answering it too

Comment: Done! As I am new in MVC3 so I though to bloat as much code as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the namespace where the [`.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method is defined:

```
using System.Linq;
```

to the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

These functions are "Extension Methods", defined in Linq. That's why you need to reference System.Linq regardless of whether you are using Entity Framework or not.

> Add the namespace where the .ToList() extension method is defined:
>
> `using System.Linq;`
>
> to the top of your file.