# Past model to Partial View with Scaffold Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Borrowed the example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810556/returning-to-view-as-tolist-not-working).

Controller:

```
EmployeeEntities storeDB = new EmployeeEntities();
         public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var employee = storeDB.Employees.ToList() 
                return View(employee);
            }
```

Model (`DbContext` class)

```
 public class EmployeeEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Assume `EmployeeEntities` is in `Models.Employees` namespace. Now I want to create a partial view. Which one should I do?

```
// A:
@model Models.Employees.EmployeeEntities.Employees

// or B:
@model List<Employee>
```

or something else? Can I use a `ViewBag` as model?

Comment: Your method is returning `List<Employee>` so its `@model List<Employee>`. And why in the world would you want to use `ViewBag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action in controller

```
EmployeeEntities storeDB = new EmployeeEntities();
         public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var employee = storeDB.Employees.ToList(); 
                return View(employee);
            }
```

According to the above code, you can see that your View Model is `List<Employee>`

```
List<Employee> employee = storeDB.Employees.ToList();
```

So in your view

```
@using namespace_of_employee_class
@model List<Employee>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since an object of `List<Employee>` is transferred to view, the namespace of the model in view is not related to the namespace of CONTEXT class (here class EmployeeEntities). It's something with the namespace of your model class (here class Employee).

I think it should be

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.Employees.Employee>
```

this assumes that class Employee is in namespace 'Models.Employees'.

Comment: I thought the object that's transferred to the view was **storeDB.Employees.ToList()**